How to count all files recursive inside a specific folder programmatically in powershell?
How can I count all files recursive inside a specific folder in a document library by powershell? So he needs to count also the files inside the subfolders recursive.

Have a look at this /Get the number of files and folders in library/
https://github.com/PowershellScripts/SharePointOnline-ScriptSamples/tree/develop/Lists%20and%20Libraries%20Management/Get%20the%20number%20of%20files%20and%20folders%20in%20library
/Get SPO Files from a folder/
https://github.com/PowershellScripts/SharePointOnline-ScriptSamples/tree/develop/File%20Management/Get%20SPO%20Files%20from%20a%20folder
Or if you prefer PnP - this example counts all files recursively inside a specific folder
https://github.com/PowershellScripts/SharePointOnline-ScriptSamples/tree/develop/File%20Management/CountFiles/InSpecificFolder

and what about if I would like to know how many files inheriting the same permissions as the specific folder?

That's a cool question. I will write that for you, but give me a weekend for that

Hi, Many thanks

hi, did you write it last weekend?

Let me know if that works for you

How many files are inheriting the same permissions as the specific folder?
$folderRelativeUrl = "/sites/yoursite/Shared Documents/YourFolder"
$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderRelativeUrl

# Retrieve all files in the folder
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -Folder $folder -ItemType File
$totalFileCount = $files.Count


$inheritedPermissionsCount = 0

# Loop through each file and check if it inherits permissions
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents" -Id $file.ListItemAllFields.Id
    if ($listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $false) {
        $inheritedPermissionsCount++
    }
}

Write-Output "Total number of files in the folder: $totalFileCount"
Write-Output "Number of files inheriting permissions: $inheritedPermissionsCount"

